# date calculation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I am trying to do some date calculations like below:

> ```
> library(optionstrat)
> #compute the difference between two dates
> tdiff("2022-10-20", "2022-11-30", "days") # return with an integer of 41, which is good. 
> tdiff(Sys.Date()-1, "2022-11-30", "days") # return with ***41.66***
> ```

Wondering what I did wrong in the third line, and may I ask how do I make it as an integer instead? Thank you so much.

Comment: File a bug report with `optionsstrat`, its `tdiff()` function should accept _both_ a formatted date (always subect to error) _and of course an actual date object that is already parsed_.  No reason not to, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply dates as `character` scalars it seems to work

```r
library(opionstrat)
tdiff(format(Sys.Date() - 1, "%Y-%m-%d"), "2022-11-30", "days")
```

Unfortunately, the documentation for `optionstrat::tdiff` is not very detailed. [It seems](https://github.com/cran/optionstrat/blob/30551766b5b42c6d2174e196b2711626b555d6b1/R/optionstrat.R#L764) that `tdiff` simply calls `difftime` under the hood. `difftime` in turn needs two time points, either as a `POSIXct`/`Date` object or as something that is coercible to a `POSIXct`/`Date` object. It seems that providing `time1` and `time2` in different formats (one as a `Date` object and one as a `character` scalar) does not work well.

(Tangential) PS. I don't really see the point of `optionstrat::tdiff`, seeing that it's really just `difftime` with the two time points swapped.